# Adding text to a canvas with HTML5 when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick

Hello I am writing the functionality to allow the user to add a title to the cavnas. Currently what happens when I click the button is the text appears for a split second in the desired position and then disappears.

Code:

```
function addTitle2(){
var title = document.getElementById("titleValue").value;
if(title === ""){
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Nothing entered";

}else {
    //Add The text to canvas:
    var a = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
    var context = a.getContext("2d");

    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.strokeStyle = "black";

    context.font = "35px Arial";
    context.fillText(title,900,50);
    context.stroke();
}

}
```

Method Call:

```
<table id="table">
                                    <form action="index.html" id="form" method="post">
                    <tr>
                    <td class="td"><input class="button" type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/></td>
                    <td class="td"><input type="text" id="titleValue" class="field" name="title"/></td>
                    <td class="td"><input class="button" type="submit" id ="titleAdd" name="addTitle" value="Add Title" onclick="addTitle2();" /></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </form>
                    </table>
```

Also if the input box is left blank and submit is clicked my error (display outside the div in a p tag) appears in the same brief fashion.

HTML in full:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <title> Graph</title>
</head>

<body onload="drawGraph()" >
    <div id="main">
        <div id="canvasCont">
        <canvas id="theCanvas" width="1100" height="400"></canvas>
        </div>
            <div id="input"> 
                <form>
                    <select class="dropdown" id="Monday" onchange="getPick(this)" name="monday">
                        <option value="0">0</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="95">95</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class="dropdown"  id="Tuesday" onchange="getPick(this)" name="tuesday">
                    <option value="0">0</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="95">95</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class="dropdown"  id="Wednesday" onchange="getPick(this)" name="wednesday">
                        <option value="0">0</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="95">95</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class="dropdown"  id="Thursday" onchange="getPick(this)" name="thursday">
                        <option value="0">0</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="95">95</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class="dropdown"  id="Friday" onchange="getPick(this)" name="friday">
                        <option value="0">0</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="95">95</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class="dropdown"  id="Saturday" onchange="getPick(this)" name="saturday">
                        <option value="0">0</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="95">95</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class="dropdown"  id="Sunday" onchange="getPick(this)" name="sunday">
                        <option value="0">0</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="45">45</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="70">70</option>
                        <option value="75">75</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="95">95</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
                <div id="inputCont">
                <form action="index.html" id="form" method="post">
                    <table id="table">

                    <tr>
                    <td class="td"><input class="button" type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/></td>
                    <td class="td"><input type="text" id="titleValue" class="field" name="title"/></td>
                    <td class="td"><input class="button" type="submit" id ="titleAdd" name="addTitle" value="Add Title" onclick="addTitle2();" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    </table>
                    </form>

                    </div>
            </div><!-- End Input Div -->
            <p id="error"> </p>

    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: `<form>` is not allowed as immediate child of `<table>`. Move it outside the `<table>`. Then, where's the `<canvas>`?

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the `addTitle()` method from a `submit` button. You see the change just for a second because, when you click the button, the form is submitted to the server (By default, to the same URL) so your page reloads and everything is just like the first time you load the page.

Do you want the form to be submitted when you push that button? If you do, then you must find another way to change the canvas upon page reload, after processing the form server-side. If you don't, just change the `type` attribute of the button from `submit` to `button`. This way, the form won't be sent to the server when you click on that button.

**EDIT** aligning the text with the right side of the canvas:

```
var a = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
var width = a.clientWidth; //canvas width.
var context = a.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.strokeStyle = "black";

context.font = "35px Arial";
context.textAlign = 'right'; //set alignment of text to the right of the 'x' position
                             //indicated in fillText()
context.fillText(title,width,50);
context.stroke();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I guess the form doesn't need to be submitted as such. I have tried your suggestion and it works however I have another question. How would you add the text to the canvas in such a way that it appears from the right (i.e, the more text written, the further to the left it indents from the right?)

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say. You mean you want the text aligned to the right? as if using `text-align: right`?

Comment: I think you mean that, so I've updated the post to show you how you can align the text with the right side of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your website is submitting the form (which is reloading the page). You should prevent it. The easiest way to do this is by returning `FALSE` in the `submit` event handler. So, instead of adding an event handler for `click` do it for the `submit` event.

Also remember to put the `<form>` outside the `<table>` as I stated in the comment.

**HTML**:

```
<form action="index.html" id="form" method="post">
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="td"><input class="button" type="submit" name="save" value="Save"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input type="text" id="titleValue" class="field" name="title"/></td>
            <td class="td"><input class="button" type="submit" id ="titleAdd" name="addTitle" value="Add Title" onsubmit="addTitle2();" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function addTitle2(){
    var title = document.getElementById("titleValue").value;
    if (title === "") {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Nothing entered";
    } else {
        //Add The text to canvas:
        var a = document.getElementById("theCanvas");
        var context = a.getContext("2d");

        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.strokeStyle = "black";

        context.font = "35px Arial";
        context.fillText(title,900,50);
        context.stroke();
    }

    return false; // <-- prevent the form from submitting
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I have positioned the form tags as you've said. I tried your fix but couldn't get it to work but changing the input type to a button as Oscar Paz suggested did the trick.